# Gluon Maps doesn't load the map and throws an exception

Tags: android, openstreetmap, gluon-mobile

When using `Gluon Maps` on android the actual map doesn't get loaded. Instead the empty white space is shown, and I can see this in logs:

```
05-31 14:20:34.041 E/CachedOsmTileRetriever(18834): null
05-31 14:20:34.041 E/CachedOsmTileRetriever(18834): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/16/33497/22228.png
05-31 14:20:34.041 E/CachedOsmTileRetriever(18834):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
05-31 14:20:34.041 E/CachedOsmTileRetriever(18834):     at com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.doCache(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:189)
05-31 14:20:34.041 E/CachedOsmTileRetriever(18834):     at com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.run(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:157)
```

The code itself is trivial:

```
private void showMap(Double lat, Double lon) {
    mapView = new MapView();
    PoiLayer poiLayer = new PoiLayer();
    MapPoint mapPoint = new MapPoint(lat, lon);
    poiLayer.addPoint(mapPoint, new Circle(7, Color.RED));
    mapView.setZoom(16);
    mapView.addLayer(poiLayer);
    mapView.flyTo(0.1, mapPoint, 0.1);
    tabMap.setContent(mapView);
}
```

The same code works just fine on iOS: the map is loaded as expected.

Using

```
compile 'com.gluonhq:maps:1.0.2'
```

in build.gradle (same thing with `1.0.3`)

Note, that if I enter the URL (from the exception mentioned above) in browser, I get redirected to https:

http://tile.openstreetmap.org/16/33497/22228.png
to
https://tile.openstreetmap.org/16/33497/22228.png

Any ideas why the exception on android?

Comment: Can you debug your network traffic to see the actual answer from the webserver? I.e. error code and error message. Maybe your request is invalid, for example if it contains no valid HTTP user-agent. See https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ for details.

Comment: Also see the current discussion about error code 403 on the OSM dev list: https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2019-May/030629.html.

Comment: What do you mean by "my" request? I'm not writing any requests myself, it should be encapsulated in the Gluon Maps code. Also note, that on iOS everything works fine. Though I'll see if I can get the webserver's response.

Comment: I was referring to the HTTP request your app is sending, regardless of the exact code part that is responsible for creating/sending it.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/16/39610/20480.png

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)

    at com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.doCache(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:189)

    at com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.run(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:157)

Comment: Though it's on desktop, not on android, but the exception seems to be of the same origin.

Comment: @oleg97 I've posted a possible solution that works for me on desktop. Can you verify it?

Comment: @José Pereda The solution works for desktop indeed. But still the same exception on android.

Comment: @oleg97 I've edited my answer, after testing on Android and iOS. Can you verify it again?

Comment: @José Pereda Yes, I've already made the same trick myself and can confirm it works on android. In my case the http.agent is:
`06-10 11:12:25.795 I/System.out(10184): HTTP.AGENT: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; SM-G965F Build/PPR1.180610.011)`

Comment: Ok, good to know. I've updated the issue on Gluon Maps.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something has changed recently from the OpenStreetMaps servers. Gluon Maps fails on desktop as well.

I've tested with `http`, and I get the reported 403 error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/5/19/10.png
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1913)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
        at com.gluonhq.maps/com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.doCache(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:190)
        at com.gluonhq.maps/com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.run(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:157)
```

and also with `https`, and now I get a different error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/6/37/22.png
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1913)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
        at com.gluonhq.maps/com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.doCache(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:190)
        at com.gluonhq.maps/com.gluonhq.impl.maps.tile.osm.CachedOsmTileRetriever$CacheThread.run(CachedOsmTileRetriever.java:157)
```

In both cases (http or https), the URL works fine on a browser, which might suggest the need of adding `"User-agent"` to the URLConnection [request](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/blob/master/maps/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/impl/maps/tile/osm/CachedOsmTileRetriever.java#L175).

Initially this seemed to solve the issue, as there were no more http errors. However the tiles were blank.

Finally, the solution that fully worked for me, at least on desktop, was this one:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Gluon Mobile/1.0.3");
}
```

Since this is a system property, it can be added to the project that uses Gluon Maps, so it can be tested before a new release is done to solve this [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/issues/33).

**Android**

On Android it looks like you need to set a valid agent.

Again, this is far from a solution, but it is a quick fix.

Add to your project, and deploy to your Android device:

```
static {
    String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
    System.out.println("HTTP.AGENT: " + userAgent);
    System.setProperty("http.agent", userAgent);
}
```

With your device plugged, open a terminal, go to the Android SDK folder, and type:

```
cd platform-tools
adb logcat -v threadtime
```

And now launch the application and see the console for the output.

In my case, I see:

```
06-10 09:57:40.784 32630 32656 I System.out: HTTP.AGENT: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; Pixel XL Build/PQ3A.190505.001)
```

which means Android provides a valid agent, but somehow it has to be explicitly set.

Now the tiles are downloaded.

However, once this is working, I can *remove* this static block from my app, and install it again fresh. And the tiles are downloaded as well. It looks like it has to be done only once. Maybe the OSM servers include that agent/device/app bundle/IP in a whitelist, but this is just a pure speculation.

**iOS**

As mentioned, on iOS it works just fine, even if `user.agent` returns null.

**EDIT**

Finally, a proper solution can be this:

```
static {
    String httpAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
    if (httpAgent == null) {
        httpAgent = "(" + System.getProperty("os.name") + " / " + System.getProperty("os.version") + " / " + System.getProperty("os.arch") + ")";
    }
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Gluon Mobile/1.0.3 " + httpAgent);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but faking the user-agent is a bad idea. This app seems to violate [OSM's tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). OSM servers run entirely on donated resources. Please update your answer and set a valid user-agent pointing to Gluon Maps, not to Mozilla.

Comment: @scai Sorry for the invalid user-agent name, I've edited the answer, with a proper fix. Hope you will reconsider the downvote.